# Three columns float with 1px space inside?

Tags: css

can anyone help me to find a CSS solution here, please?
here is a scribble:

[image: Scribble]

The wrapper has a variable width and the inside space of the floating boxes should exactly 1px. the margin-bottom is no problem - but the margin on the left/right side. how to solve this with width:33%?? :(

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: this would be a mobile friendly page. so there are fewer columns if the browser size is smaller. i will do this with @media.

Comment: What browsers are you supporting? IE 7+? IE 6?

Comment: not really :) but if there a way - why not...

Comment: and is there a set number of boxes? Will there always be 6 boxes?

Comment: no... that should be variable. there is a dynamic "load-more"function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="Dummy">


    <div class="insideDummy">aloha</div>
    <div class="insideDummy">aloha</div>
    <div class="insideDummy">aloha</div>
    <div class="insideDummy">aloha</div>
    <div class="insideDummy">aloha</div>
    <div class="insideDummy">aloha</div>



</div>
```

where

```
.Dummy{float:left; min-width:99.9%; height:auto; background:#999999; float:left;}


.insideDummy{ float:left; width:33.25%; min-width:10%; height:300px; background:#99FFCC; margin-left:1px; margin-top:1px;}
```

Extremely fluid design. some glitches may be visible in different resolutions, but should work in most cases.

Comment: yeah, i know these glitches and therefore i've opened this thread :D it's tricky.

Comment: If you don't want any glitches, then its not possible using css and html alone. You have two choice:
1. Either use table
2. Or use javascript to calculate the viewport of browser window and adjust the dimensions of your child containers.

Thank you.

Comment: hmm... yeah i've written a script for this but hoped there is a css-only solution :/

Comment: yes, its not possible with css because you are trying to mix pixels and percents together. You always have to stick to one metric system when designing. 1px of gap between boxes having 33.3% width which are in turn inside 100% width box! - Trouble is right here. Browsers do not understand this. Browsers are like 3 months old child, feed them with right food otherwise it'll poop green.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to mix percents and pixels in the manner in which you are thinking. However, you can do the following:

```css
.innerdiv {
    display: inline-block; /* IE 8+ Compatible because IE 7 only supports inline-block on elements that are inline by default. There are work-arounds to this though. */
    width: 30%;
    margin: 2%; /* gutter */
}
```

That said, you can also use:

```
.wrapper {
    column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 1px;
    -moz-column-gap: 1px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1px;
}
```

The ordering of the columns, however, is fill in the left and then move onto the next item, so using this will mess up your ordering, but balance the height. The other CSS to use would be `grid-columns` but that is not supported yet, so no use coding for it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

A sort of what you want may be achieved with `display: table`, `table-row`, `table-cell`.
Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/FtYqe/7/  This will not work in IE7 and older.

Comment: @PhilippKühn How do you want to display it if there is 5 or 7 inner div's?

Comment: i'll generate "spacer" to fill the row. so there are alway 3,6,9,12,15... divs to float.